# Issue with sequelize migrations to heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, sequelize.js

I have been sitting at this computer for 7 hours straight trying to deploy my app. There is a node/express backend serving up restricted API json data at different endpoints. In order to get access to this json data you have to have a token.

It all works fine and dandy on my local server during development. However, when I go to send the migrations to heroku (using 'heroku run bash', then 'sequelize db:migrate), I get some random error saying "SyntaxError: Unexpected String"..as shown below.

As you can see, when I run sequelize:db:migrate:undo, it says that no executed migrations found.

```
    Sequelize [Node: 5.11.1, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.24.3, pg: ^6.1.0]

```
Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "production".
== 20160917224717-create-user: migrating =======
[SyntaxError: Unexpected string]
~ $ sequelize db:migrate:undo

Sequelize [Node: 5.11.1, CLI: 2.4.0, ORM: 3.24.3, pg: ^6.1.0]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "production".
No executed migrations found.
~ $
```

```

However, when I look in my heroku database, I DO see that there is now 1 table. However, that table does not work, and I am still getting an error on form submit to create a user. The error I get on form submit is:

message: "relation "users" does not exist"
name: "SequelizeDatabaseError"

What gives? This alleged syntax unexpected string error does not throw when I am running locally. It runs smooth as butter with the migrations. What could this be?

Thanks.

Comment: Figured out the problem. There was an unexpected number 2 placed at the top of the user migration file. Which is why it was stopping at user migration. The thing that threw everything off was that it wasn't telling me WHERE the unexpected string was. So if you're reading this in the future with the same error message, just know that you probably accidentally have an unexpected string somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Either you have not updated your code on the server to match your local environment or your database does not match.  "Users relation" implies the `users` table is related to *another table*.  Make sure the code is really updated (if sequelize code mentions this relation) AND all other tables are reproduced on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Once I got a problem with accessing postgres db on Heroku (provided as an add-on):

- I installed `SQL Shell (psql)` on my laptop
- I logged-in to the db (used all necessary credentials)
- run: `\dt` to check db schema => result: 'no relations', so the migration wasn't done yet
- run `migrate:db`
- run: `\dt` => schema is here - OK!
- now: run heroku console
- login to your account
- run: `heroku restart -a=<my_app>`

If the lack of db:migration was a problem only, it should be fine now.

You can also try to reset your db first (if your data isn't precious!) running: `heroku pg:reset -a=<my_app>`